# Send Data From C program to Command Line Password Prompt

Tags: c, command-line, ssh

The ssh command line command prompts the user for a password like so:

Password:

In C, when I do:

```
system("ssh name@host");
system("password");
```

the command line will prompt the user and ignore any input coming from my program. It seems to always take input that's typed by the user. Is there a way to redirect output that I'm putting to stdout and pipe it into the password prompt for ssh?

I've tried a variety of things, from above to treating ssh as a file pointer like so:

```
FILE *ssh = popen("ssh -t -t -S -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no name@host", "w");
```

and then writing to that file pointer but none seem to work.

Comment: search here for `[bash] ssh password` to see what you're  up against. You can use `expect` to 'type in' your password, else use the ssh feature public-key password files, or of course, reinvent `expect`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are coding in `C` **consider using [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/)**. See [this example](http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_exec.html).

There are more examples [here](http://www.libssh2.org/examples/).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. SSH will open `/dev/tty` and read the password directly from that, so there's no way you can pass it any input that way. I know of no way to override that behavior, apart from using `libssh2`, as shiplu said.

Comment: Mannnnn. Is that how the security tool Hydra did that? I've been trolling through the source code but it's slow going.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternate way to solve your problem - `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`.

Essentially, you copy the public key to the host once; on any connections after that, `ssh` will automatically use its private key to log in.

Run

```
ssh-keygen
```

Hit enter 3 times. Run:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

And type your password.

That's it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im In what way?

Comment: "Hit enter 3 times" thats a password less key

Comment: I should mention, the point of this exercise is because I'm building my own bruteforce engine from scratch. It's break and I'm bored. Plus it sounds like fun.

Comment: @shadow bruteforce  technique takes a long time. You shouldn't use `system` function here at all. It'll slow you down.

Comment: I have nothing but time so no worries. And I know bruteforce takes forever but I figure if I want to be a penetration tester, building my own from the group up isnt a terrible idea.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Is a passwordless key less secure than hardcoding the password into your program? If somebody gains read access to your program's binary, they can run `strings` against it and instantly recover your password anyway. Plus, if you password the key, then you need to input the password on `/dev/tty`. You are back to square one.

Comment: @shadow Neat project! Sorry, I misunderstood what your goals were. libssh2 is the way to go for a bruteforcer.